# my camera do not work on my new device (nullpointerexcepetion)

Tags: android, parameters, nullpointerexception, android-camera

after i changed my device my camera suddently stopped working and throwing out a

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.Camera$Parameters android.hardware.Camera.getParameters()' on a null object reference

i had tryed to change out my `catch (RuntimeException ex)` to `finaly`
but that instead gaved me a

> Fail to connect to camera service” exception

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    String PreviewFPS;
    String Previewsize;
    String Displayor;
    PreviewFPS = setingPreferences.getString("previewfps", "");
    Previewsize = setingPreferences.getString("screensize", "");
    Displayor = setingPreferences.getString("orientation", "");
    String[] size = Previewsize.split(",");
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    }
    Camera.Parameters parameters;
  parameters = camera.getParameters();

    //modificer parameterene
          parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(Integer.parseInt(PreviewFPS));
        parameters.setPreviewSize(Integer.parseInt(size[0]),Integer.parseInt(size[1]));
     camera.setParameters(parameters);
    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
   camera.setDisplayOrientation(Integer.parseInt(Displayor));
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

}
```

manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

the manufactor of the device had investigated the code and told me that the reason was due to it couldn't run the scanner and camera at once

> Hi Kewin
>    
>   Would you please share the source code to me? as we haven't tested if it can run both the camera and scanner
>
> We checked, the scanner and camera can not be opened in same time.
>    
>   Best Regards,

so my fix for this was by having my camera and scanner activity running in 2 separate activites and layouts hopefully this would help someone else

Comment: try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

check output logs

Comment: It's not supposed to fix the error, it's supposed to show you the logs of what went wrong

Comment: that was not the solution.It will print logs why camera is not initialized.Due to exception here camera is still null

Comment: have you added permissions or runtime permission(>=M) for camera

Comment: give us the camera object definition. obviously you didn't initialize it correctly.

Comment: it was none of thoose things that was the issue it was related to the RFID since it couldn't handle both cam and RFID at once so after i turned the RFID off my camera got fully functional again

Answer (score 0):

You need all the camera code in the try and you should read the stacktraces if you actually printed them

```
try {
    camera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

   ... 
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

// camera remains null if an exception is caught...
```

Comment: thats the only thing i see in my stacktrace analyzer
 `System.err:     at com.kewin.device.CameraActivity.surfaceCreated(CameraActivity.java:397)`

and thats 
 `camera = Camera.open();`

Comment: Then I'd suggest reading the documentation for the open() method there and see if it says why any exceptions are thrown

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen ... because you obviously didn't create an object called `camera` of type `Camera`.

Comment: @Kewin that class is deprecated, so I don't know why you're even using it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: i have it here android.hardware.Camera camera;

Comment: That package is entirely deprecated. Read the documentation, please